# Node.js define sub-object by variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have an File (*default.js*) which defines an Object like so

```
return {
    parent: {
        "default": {
            other_properties: true
        },
    },
    another_parent: {
        "default": {
            other_properties: true
        },
    }
}
```

and does nothing else than returning that Object.
But the child object, which has to be named of the current file (eg. `"default"`) stays always the same.

I'd like to be able to have the child-object named after the current file.
Is that possible on the initial declaration?

Other than that, I already know I can get the filename using

```
var path = require('path');
var filename = path.basename(__filename);
```

Comment: Presumably the filename isn't going to change either, no...!?

Comment: The file won't change. But it will get copied and build upon on from others, who are barely familiar with it. It would be practical to avoid problems.